# How do I make floating forms such as in Lazarus or Photoshop using C#?

Tags: c#, multiple-forms

How do I make it so when a program loads, it opens multiple forms, but they're like tools, such as in the Lazarus IDE there are multiple windows that all affect each other?

Comment: That's pretty unclear, windows float by design.  Create tool windows by using the Show(owner) overload.  It ensures the tool window also stays above the main window.

Comment: I think you should manage it by yourself. I'm not familiar with Lazaruz, but looking on images on their website it seems to me that they use regular windowses like toolboxes. So I think if you want to implement kind of "docking" for windowsforms you should handle it by yourself, or you can implement user controls that look like windowsform, but I think this is much complicated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a multiple document interface (MDI) application, commonly used where windows reside under a single parent window.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface

Advice on creating such applications is a broad subject - but the followings links should help you on your path:

- [Creating MDI application using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/myBestMDI.aspx)
- [Introduction to MDI Forms with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mdiformstutorial.aspx)
- [Developing MDI Applications in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp11272005225843PM/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp.aspx)
- [Multiple-Document Interface (MDI) Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e.aspx)

Good luck and feel free to ask about any specific problems you have.